# Error calling webapi from sharepoint

Tags: jquery, ssl, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-2010

I've got a sharepoint webpart that makes a jquery ajax call to a webapi, but when inspecting the call with fiddler i get a error message that says "Session #84: The remote server (srvkbhnws001) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateNameMismatch." Now the client calling is on the domain mydomain.local, the webserver that hosts the webapi is on the same domain. Now the traffic has to be over https so there is a certificate installed on the machines but it is issued to *.mydomain.dk. Is the that the root of the problem, and if so...how do I fix it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the issue is with the domain mismatch on the certificate, but I'm not knowledgeable enough with sharepoint to be able to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

OK first thing you need to do is to Export your root cert in to a file.cert.

Wnd+r and type mmc go to certs find your root cert and export it, for the sake of time and space you will be good if you get to this screen:

[image]

Now you have to go to Sharepoint central admin:

> - Central Administration > Security >Manage Trust

Click to **new** to add a new trust:

[image]

and this screen will appear:

[image]

Upload there your root cert Click and you will be good to go.

> **Important:** If it is a 2 Level root cert please upload both the second root cert as new root cert in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that the mismatch was caused by the way that I called my webservice. I called my webservice with https://[servername]/[servicename]/[api]/[operation]. But I the server name has to have the domain attached in order to satisfy the certicate so when I changed the DNS mapping so that I could call my service with *.domain.dk/[servicename]/[api]/[operation] the problem was solved.